# How do I create a rule that moves an email to another file after it is marked complete?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I would like to create a rule that moves an email to another file after it is marked complete.  I have tried all of the standard rule sets that I thought might work.  I have searched online and found some software offerings but they did not seem to address this issue either.

Comment: What do you mean after the email is marked "Complete"?  Do you mean marked "Read"?

Comment: No, on the right side of the preview where you can categorize by color and flag for future action, you can click to the check mark to indicate complete or select complete from the follow up list in the options section of the ribbon,

Comment: You need to use the stop processing more rules option and it will do it

Comment: I believe the problem lies in the fact you can only choose as the message arrives or as the message is sent.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: I added an illustrative image. Myself and my co-workers want this as well.

Comment: Similar question, for Outlook 2011: https://superuser.com/questions/1045533/how-do-i-set-up-a-rule-to-trigger-for-emails-marked-as-complete