# How do I set up a rule to trigger for emails marked as "complete"?

Tags: email, email-filter, microsoft-outlook-2011

> Related question, but for Outlook 2007: [How do I create a rule that moves an email to another file after it is marked complete?](https://superuser.com/q/887870/410489)

There is a feature of Outlook 2011 which lets you mark flag a message as complete:

[image: The Office 2011 Home tab's Flag dropdown, containing "Today, Tomorrow, This Week, Next Week, No Due Date, Custom Date..., Add Reminder..., Mark as Complete, and Clear Flag".]

I would like to create a rule that deletes an email after it is marked complete (or, under other conditions, move it to a folder, assign a category to it, etc.), but I don't see any way to do so.

The problem seems to stem from the fact that a message can be selected by its binary flag status, but nothing more specific than that:

[image: The Outlook 2011 rule creation dialog. "Rule name" is "Delete 'Done'". "When a message arrives" contains only the rule "Status is Flagged", but shows other options: "Flagged, Read, Unread, Replied To, Forwarded, Redirected". "Do the following" is set to "Delete Message". "Do not apply other rules to messages matching these conditions" is checked. "Enabled" is checked.]

Comment: If you're marking it complete, why wouldn't you just delete it instead of marking it. Alternatively, you can perhaps create a new search folder to query all the flagged items or by Categorized mail, then periodically select all for deletion

Comment: @Lex Because I want to involve other, more complex rules in this process. For instance, I want to go down my email-style task list and mark things as done, then select all and run all rules to have it sort out ones from managers to one folder, automated ones to trash, ones by me to yet another folder, etc.